# How to display an API populated virtual folder in Windows Common File Dialogs

Tags: c++, windows, openfiledialog, savefiledialog, common-dialog

We have a REST API that we can use to get a list of files, upload and download files. Now we need to integrate this API in one of our application so that users can open and save files using the API.
I want to make the UI consistent with opening and saving a normal file. Instead of creating new dialogs, I believe the Common File Dialogs can be tweaked to display a virtual folder populated using the API. A new location can be added on the list on the left hand side. Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The "Open File Dialog" is just the Windows Shell component. You're looking for [`IShellFolder` and friends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096(v=vs.85).aspx).

As for adding it to a *Common Item Dialog*, that would be done via [`IFileDialog::AddPlace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775946(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I was thinking maybe this can be done by using Dialog hooks. Is it possible to tweak the open/save dialogs in just my application by somehow attaching a IShellFolder based object to dialogs.

Comment: @A9S6: Sounds quite painful.